# Java code for testing Solr token filters?

Tags: java, solr

I tried to write a Java code to see how Solr token filters are working.

```
  public class TestFilter {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    StringReader inputText = new StringReader("This is a TEST string");
    Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
    param.put("luceneMatchVersion", "LUCENE_44");

    TokenizerFactory stdTokenFact = new StandardTokenizerFactory(param);
    Tokenizer tokenizer = stdTokenFact.create(inputText);

    param.put("luceneMatchVersion", "LUCENE_44");
    LowerCaseFilterFactory lowerCaseFactory = new LowerCaseFilterFactory(param);
    TokenStream tokenStream = lowerCaseFactory.create(tokenizer);

    CharTermAttribute termAttrib = (CharTermAttribute) tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
    System.out.println("CharTermAttribute Length = " + termAttrib.length());
    while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
      String term = termAttrib.toString();
      System.out.println(term);
    }
  }
}
```

I got this output and error message.

```
CharTermAttribute Length = 0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizerImpl.zzRefill(StandardTokenizerImpl.java:923)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizerImpl.getNextToken(StandardTokenizerImpl.java:1133)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer.incrementToken(StandardTokenizer.java:171)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.LowerCaseFilter.incrementToken(LowerCaseFilter.java:54)
    at com.utsav.solr.TestFilter.main(TestFilter.java:31)
```

Why is `termAttrib.length()` giving zero?

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following [the JavaDoc of TokenStream](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenStream.html)

> The workflow of the new TokenStream API is as follows:
>
> 1. Instantiation of TokenStream/TokenFilters which add/get attributes to/from the AttributeSource.
> 2. The consumer calls TokenStream.reset().
> 3. The consumer retrieves attributes from the stream and stores local references to all attributes it wants to access.
> 4. The consumer calls incrementToken() until it returns false consuming the attributes after each call.
> 5. The consumer calls end() so that any end-of-stream operations can be performed.
> 6. The consumer calls close() to release any resource when finished using the TokenStream.

You would need to rewrite your method as follows

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    StringReader inputText = new StringReader("This is a TEST string");
    Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
    param.put("luceneMatchVersion", "LUCENE_44");

    TokenizerFactory stdTokenFact = new StandardTokenizerFactory(param);
    Tokenizer tokenizer = stdTokenFact.create(inputText);

    param.put("luceneMatchVersion", "LUCENE_44");
    LowerCaseFilterFactory lowerCaseFactory = new LowerCaseFilterFactory(param);
    TokenStream tokenStream = lowerCaseFactory.create(tokenizer);

    CharTermAttribute termAttrib = (CharTermAttribute) tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

    tokenStream.reset();

    while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
        System.out.println("CharTermAttribute Length = " + termAttrib.length());

        System.out.println(termAttrib.toString());
    }

    tokenStream.end();
    tokenStream.close();
}
```

This generated the following output

```
CharTermAttribute Length = 4
this
CharTermAttribute Length = 2
is
CharTermAttribute Length = 1
a
CharTermAttribute Length = 4
test
CharTermAttribute Length = 6
string
```

**Edit** As mentioned in the comment, it is not required to call `tokenStream.getAttribute` consequentially, as is pointed out in the JavaDoc

> Note that only one instance per AttributeImpl is created and reused for every token. This approach reduces object creation and allows local caching of references to the AttributeImpls.

Comment: Is it necessary to put `tokenStream.getAttribute` inside while loop?